# Handle exception when using hyperlink for downloading a file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, hyperlink, filenotfoundexception

I am using a hyperlink in my grid and I am downloading the file which has been stored in my applications folder. It works fine when the file is present in the folder but if tested that I delete the file and then try to download the I get an error as `The resource cannot be found.` and my page crashes. How to handle this exception of file not found? I applied debug point on my PageLoad also but the debug is not coming there.

here is my aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOWNLOAD">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PATH") %>' >Download</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderColor="#DDDDDD" Font-Size="14px"
                        ForeColor="#333333" Font-Names="Calibri" />

                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" BorderWidth="0px" ForeColor="#333333"
                        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="14px"></ItemStyle>

                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Set the ClientIDMode to Static not necessary though.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PATH") %>' Target="_blank" >Download</asp:HyperLink>
```

Check on page load(on bowser) if the file exists or not:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var url = jQuery("#HyperLink1").prop('href');
        jQuery.get(url).done(function () {
            // File exists so do nothing
        }).fail(function () { // doesn't exist so reset parameters accordingly
            jQuery("#HyperLink1").prop('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
            jQuery("#HyperLink1").attr('target', '_self');
        })
    });
```

put this tag in the head section, this will reference jquery library hosted by Google

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: And which version of .js file I should use.?

Comment: no check using jquery in the aspx file, put this method in the head section and also make sure you add reference to Jquery. use any latest jquery version. you can also put a reference to the one hosted by google or download on your machine.... check update